# get inner span from clicked elment in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="pm1"><span class="from"><span class="plusminus" class="pm plus">TEXT1...
<div class="pm1"><span class="from"><span class="plusminus" class="pm plus">TEXT2...
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".pm1").click(function () {
```

and now I would like to get clicked span by class = plusminus

but I don't know how to get it , i have tried like `$(this).find(xxx)` but does not work.

What can I do?

EDIT.

I changed id to class

Comment: try this $(this).closest('span.pm')

Comment: @bhushya it has to be `.find()`, not `.closest()`

Comment: $(".pm1").click(function () { $(this).find('#plusminus'); });

Comment: I know :D Not quite sure what op wants :)

Comment: @senzacionale do you know that for adequate work elements ID must be unique?

Comment: You have error in your html :) Multiple ids with same name. Every id must be unique :)

Comment: `var $span =  $(this).find('.pm'), id = $span.attr('id')` should do it.... also as other has said ID of an element must be unique

Comment: Thx I changed from id to class because when you click you get a row and this row is important for me. I want to get span by class on this row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the html of grand child (id = plusminus) of the clicked element in two ways.

For example...

```
$(".pm1").click(function () {

    // Method 1 (If you know the id of grand child)
    console.log($(this).find("#plusminus").html());

    // Method 2 (If you know the structure but dont know the element)
    console.log($(this).find("span span").html());
});
```

If you want to execute it directly, then just call the below code:

```
$("#plusminus").click(function () {
    // Your code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So to find the class .plusminus inside the clicked .pm1 you should use this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".pm1").click(function () {
        var plusminus = $(this).find('.plusminus');
        //rest of your code
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to find your element

> ```
> $(this).find($("span")).find(".plusminus")
> ```

Comment: `$(this).find(".plusminus")` will look much better.

Comment: Once again: `$(this).find(".plusminus")` without any additional `.find()`. Your current version can simply be `$(this).find("span .plusminus")`

Comment: Okay. Does it matter if there are two find functions?

Comment: Two searches in DOM instead of one and more long/difficult code.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   var click_span;
   $(".pm1").click(function (){
        click_span = $(this).find('.plusminus'); 
        alert(click_span);
   }  
 }
```

This will give you object of the span,